# Pull not possible because you have unmerged files

Tags: git, github, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy our django project to AWS. Our fabfile that handles the deployment uses a git pull (of course). During the pull, we receive the error below:

```
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] Executing task 'deploy'
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] run: git pull origin master
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: U impact/c/views.py
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
[ec2-54-215-107-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] out: 


Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
```

Now I know there have been a few other users post this question on here, and believe me when I say I have read a lot of them, but none seem to work for us. There are no merge / conflict errors when committing locally, the error only seems to happen when we perform the pull from the SSH terminal of the AWS server.

Comment: Have you run `git status`?  it shuold lists the files it believes to currently be in conflict

Comment: It would help everyone involved if you could ***at least list which answers you have already tried***, so that no one here repeats themselves and work, especially for things you have already tried, because that would just waste everyone's time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does git say "Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376832/why-does-git-say-pull-is-not-possible-because-you-have-unmerged-files)

Answer (score 1):

Edit `impact/c/views.py` (in vim, nano or emacs) and you will one or more sections of

```
some stuff
>>>>>>>>>>>
(first alternative for conflict)
which may span one or more lines
===========
(second alternative for conflict)
which also may span
one or more lines
<<<<<<<<<<<
other stuff
```

Decide which is the correct alternative, delete the other and all the chevrons and equals signs.

Do `git commit -a -m"fixed views.py"` and then `git push origin master`.