# I cannot get a pull from master branch

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, gitlab, pull

I committed my local changes and there are no local changes anymore. But I cannot get an update from master branch. Can anyone help me?
[error that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsN4k.png)

Comment: You probably have some conflicting code that doesn't show up on the version control tab. You can check the log section of the VC tab. or try git merge --abort to reset the merging, if pending

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, please see here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63156
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127308

As a workaround, you can resolve the issue via command-line as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27187110/12360005), or add files via **right-click on file | Git | Add**